# error en cannot convert from string to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, archivo, filewriter

Cree una serie de métodos en una clase para leer y escribir archivos texto, y en uno de los metodos me sale error:

```
public static void CreateAllText(string path, string contenidos, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sDocwriter = new StreamWriter(path, encoding, 1, false))
            {
                sDocwriter.Write(contenidos);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Error: Existe Archivo en la Ruta Especificada");
        }
    }
```

en la linea :

> using (StreamWriter sDocwriter = new StreamWriter(**path**, encoding, 1, false))

justo en el path en tiempo de diseño es que sale el mencionado error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo estas pasando los argumentos del constructor de forma incorrecta.

Lo correcto seria:

```
using (StreamWriter sDocwriter = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding, 1))
{
    sDocwriter.Write(contenidos);
}
```

Comment: si de todo los sobrecargas creo que esta funciono, lo que no entiendo 1 es dejar abierto el archivo??

Comment: Ya estas utilizando el using y con eso el archivo se cierra. El ejemplo que te coloqué solo es para que vieras cual era el constructor correcto.

Answer (score 0):

El [constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_) que quieres utilizar es el siguiente:

```
StreamWriter(String, Boolean, Encoding, Int32)
```

Entonces tienes que cambiar tus valores, para que coincida, cambia el encoding de lugar:

```
using (StreamWriter sDocwriter = new StreamWriter(path, 1, encoding, false))
      {
            sDocwriter.Write(contenidos);
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

El constructor que estas usando no es el correcto:

Mira la documentacion de Microsoft sobre  constructores de [StreamWriter](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Cambialo por:

```
new StreamWriter(path, true, encoding, 1)
```

Comment: hola mac mira la documentacion que sugeriste public StreamWriter (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen); 1 stream, 2 encoding 3 buffersize, 4 leaveopen

Comment: @ger te equivocas, la que yo sugiero es la ultima: `StreamWriter(String, Boolean, Encoding, Int32)`